# Twitter REST API: tweet extraction

Tags: api, twitter, twitter-oauth, twitter-streaming-api, twitter-rest-api

The following code has been written by me to extract tweets with specific hashtags.

```
import json
import oauth2
import time
import io


Consumer_Key = ""
Consumer_Secret = ""

access_token = ""
access_token_secret = ""


def oauth_req(url, key, secret, http_method="GET", post_body="", http_headers=None):
        consumer = oauth2.Consumer(key="", secret="")
        token = oauth2.Token(key=key, secret=secret)
        client = oauth2.Client(consumer, token)
        content = client.request( url, method=http_method, body=post_body, headers=http_headers )
        return content

tweet_url = 'https://twitter.com/search.json?q=%23IPv4%20OR%20%23ISP%20OR%20%23WiFi%20OR%20%23Modem%20OR%20%23Internet%20OR%20%23IPV6'   
jsn = oauth_req( tweet_url, access_token, access_token_secret )
print jsn
```

My hashtags are: IPv4, IPv6, ISP, Internet, Modem. I want my code to see if a tweet has at least one of the hashtags that tweet should be written to my file.
But, unfortunately it is returning the html tags instead.
The output is as follows:

```
({'content-length': '338352', 'x-xss-protection': '1; mode=block', 'x-content-type-options': 'nosniff',........................
.............................-post-iframe" name="tweet-post-iframe"></iframe>\n  <iframe aria-hidden="true" class="dm-post-iframe" name="dm-post-iframe"></iframe>\n\n</div>\n\n  </body>\n</html>\n')
```

Any lead in this regard will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at your tweet url which is

```
tweet_url = 'https://twitter.com/search.json?q=%23IPv4%20OR%20%23ISP%20OR%20%23WiFi%20OR%20%23Modem%20OR%20%23Internet%20OR%20%23IPV6'
```

which is the url of website.
But if you are trying to extract tweets through Twitter API just replace above url with this url :

```
tweet_url = 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?q=%23IPv4%20OR%20%23ISP%20OR%20%23WiFi%20OR%20%23Modem%20OR%20%23Internet%20OR%20%23IPV6'
```