# Twitter REST api - access tweets by hashtag

Tags: java, twitter

Here is code I wrote to access tweets from a given user using the Twitter REST service :

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class GetTweets {


    private static final String BEARER_TOKEN = "test";

    public static String getTweetsByUsername(final String username) {
        final ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

        try {
            URL url = new URL("https://api.twitter.com/2/users/by/username/" + username);
            HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            con.setRequestMethod("GET");
            con.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Bearer " + BEARER_TOKEN);
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
            String inputLine;
            StringBuffer content = new StringBuffer();
            while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                content.append(inputLine);
            }
            in.close();

            final DataResponse dataResponse = objectMapper.readValue(content.toString(), DataResponse.class);

            url = new URL("https://api.twitter.com/2/users/" + dataResponse.getUserDetails().getId() + "/tweets");
            con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            con.setRequestMethod("GET");
            con.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Bearer " + BEARER_TOKEN);
            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
            content = new StringBuffer();
            while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                content.append(inputLine);
            }
            in.close();

            return content.toString();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return "None";
    }

    public static void main(String argsp[]) throws IOException {

        List<String> users = Arrays.asList("test1" , "test2");

        users.forEach(x -> {

                System.out.println(GetTweets.getTweetsByUsername(x));

        });

    }
}
```

This behaves as expected I'm unsure how to find the tweets for a given hashtag.

For example, If I use :

```
 List<String> users = Arrays.asList("#test1");
```

I receive exception :

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: https://api.twitter.com/2/users/by/username/#test1
```

What is the endpoint path to access tweets by hashtag ? I've tried `https://api.twitter.com/2/users/by/hashtag/#test1` but this does not exist.

There is a similar question here [Twitter REST API: tweet extraction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40415153/twitter-rest-api-tweet-extraction) but this refers to earlier version of api.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking the answer provided by @Egor, and enhancing it to include your other requirement, to find Tweets from a particular user with a hashtag, you can use the `from:` syntax in your query, combined with the hashtag itself.

`https://api.twitter.com/2/tweets/search/recent?query=#test1%20from:user1`

Answer (score 2):

[Search tweets doc](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/tweets/search/quick-start/recent-search)

[Search query syntax](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/tweets/search/integrate/build-a-query)

I have no access to Twitter API but the doc says it should work:

```
https://api.twitter.com/2/tweets/search/recent?query=#test
```